# Icon doesn't have the correct size (Font Awesome)

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, font-awesome

I just started working with Font Awesome for my upcoming homepage.

Right now I try to implement some social networks. So far it works great for facebook und Co., but I have a problem with one network which is called XING.

That's the code I use for LinkedIN:

```
<div class="i_iconsoc"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></div>
```

and that's what I use for XING:

```
<div class="i_iconsoc"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-xing"></i></a></div>
```

Both look the same to me, but somehow it gets displayed like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/81WN9.png

Can you help me with the problem? That's my code in the CSS file btw.

```
     .fa-xing
 {
     background:#68d49a;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

icon fonts have a attrib called: .fa where can put the font-size  used in the icon, would try modify that properties

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

i recomended to use fontello, include all font-awesome and others fonts, if you use this would do this:

```
.youritem.icon-linkedin:before{
content: '\e808';
//your font-size
font-size: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I finally found it ...
.fa-twitter,.fa-xing, .fa-linkedin{padding:11px;}
.fa-facebook
--> Was the reason!

Comment: oh! is true, i wait that my answer helped you, so... dont forget reset the margins, maybe

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  }
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #545454;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
ul li a:hover {
  color: #C86565;
  }

.fa-color1 {
  color: #0095FF;
  margin-left: 4px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
.fa-color1:hover {
  color: #6BC5EB;
  }
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>font</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Squada+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  
  <br><br><br>

  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x fa-color1"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x fa-color1"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-4x fa-color1"></i></a>
 </body>
```